# Docker-Compose not installed with Docker Desktop

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose, docker-desktop

I installed Docker Desktop v4.12.0 on windows 10 which installed docker v20.10.17.

I am trying to run `docker-compose pull` but get the response `docker: 'compose' is not a docker command`. I've tried reinstalling Docker Desktop but I still get the same error.

`docker-compose --version` and `docker compose --version` both return the same error message.

I'm new to docker and not sure if I've done something incorrectly.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Check whether docker desktop running in your machine.

Comment: Yep it's running.

Comment: Have you checked to make sure docker-compose is in your windows environment variables?

Comment: @Kelsey I added docker-compose.exe to PATH but I'm still getting the same message.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen when we have older files laying around in windows path.

Try this:

```
where docker
```

or

```
where docker-compose
```

If you have multiple paths, maybe one of them is very old.
In my case, I had to **delete** docker.exe and dockerd.exe in the root of **c:\Program Files\Docker**. The new files should be in the **resources\bin** folder.

If you are having difficulties running cmd "where" in Windows/Powershell, try this way:

```
PS C:\Users\canoas> where.exe docker
C:\Program Files\Rancher Desktop\resources\resources\win32\bin\docker.exe
C:\Program Files\Rancher Desktop\resources\resources\linux\bin\docker
PS C:\Users\canoas> where.exe docker-compose
C:\Program Files\Rancher Desktop\resources\resources\win32\bin\docker-compose.exe
C:\Program Files\Rancher Desktop\resources\resources\linux\bin\docker-compose
```

Comment: In my case, I had an old version of docker installed with chocolatey, which was found in the `C:\ProgramData\Chocolatey` folder. running `choco uninstall docker` fixed the issue for me.